# Getting Fatal Error when i save data from response

Tags: swift

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

This is my code line:

```
let View = (VArray[0] as? [String : Any])?["views_count"] as! NSNumber
```

Can anyone help me apply try catch for this line? For Swift 3.1 of 4.

Comment: you can use if..let to get the value of optionals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite easy using optional

```
if let dictView = VArray[0] as? [String : Any], let viewsCount = dictView["views_count"] as? NSNumber {
    print(viewsCount)
} else {
    print("Cannot convert to NSNumber")
}
```